# Mouse event button not working

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a button in WPF and I am creating an event handler for it.
My goal is to generate a sunken effect when the button is clicked. 
The problem is I tried different event handler and it doesn't seem to be working.
I don't see any effect at all. Any idea on how to fix it?

XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="btnMyAccount">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="165"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{StaticResource Home-MyProfile}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtMyAccount" Grid.Row="1" FontWeight="Bold">
            MY ACCOUNT
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

C# code:

```
private void btnMyAccount_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    btnMyAccount.BorderThickness = new Thickness(5, 5, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Try the one with the `Preview` prefix (`PreviewMouseDown` or smthing like this)

Comment: I tried using PreviewMouseDown event, not working as well.

Comment: does it enter the event handler method?

Comment: what do u mean? I don't see any sunken effect when i press the button

Comment: You'd be better off using Triggers or VisualStates. Refer to this MSDN [blogpost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsdk/2009/02/27/the-visualstatemanager-and-triggers/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i really want to get it work on my event handler

Comment: Everything in my code seems to check out. This is odd that the effect doesn't work.

Comment: i think having something in the `<Button></Button>` tags means you now have a custom template for your button.
You should surround the grid with a `<Border x:Name="yourBorder"></Border>` and then increase that border thinknes

Comment: Can u give an example?

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think having something in the `<Button></Button>` tags means you now have a custom template for your button. You should surround the grid with a `<Border x:Name="yourBorder"></Border>` and then increase that border thinknes

You must change you button template to look like this:

```
<Button x:Name="btnMyAccount">
    <Border x:Name="yourBorder" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="165"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{StaticResource Home-MyProfile}" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtMyAccount" Grid.Row="1" FontWeight="Bold">
                MY ACCOUNT
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Button>
```

Then in your event handler you would change the `yourBorder` thickness:

```
private void btnMyAccount_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    yourBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(5, 5, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: how would this fix it?

Comment: It didn't work, the only thing that you add is an extra black border line on the layout of my button. The effect still doesn't kick in